# cpulimit cause ffmpeg to run in background

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg, command

I try to use cpulimit to limit ffmpeg process, however it seems to cause ffmpeg to run in background

First of in the first command console, I start ffmpeg and disable all output

```
ffmpeg -i "Avengers2mp4" -hls_list_size 0 -hls_key_info_fil file.keyinfo -nostdin -loglevel quiet -threads 0 "out.m3u8"
```

next, I open another command console, find out the process ID of ffmpeg by running

```
ps -a         
PID    TTY          TIME CMD
1359   pts/0    00:00:02 ffmpeg
1364   pts/3    00:00:00 ps
```

I'm using CPUlimit version 2.0, my server has 3 cores so I set the limit to 150 (50% of the available resources) with the command

`cpulimit -l 150 -p "1359"`

and as the result of that on the first command console, it show

```
[0]+  Stopped                 ffmpeg -i "Avengers2.mp4" -hls_list_size 10000 -hls_key_info_file file.keyinfo -nostdin -loglevel quiet -threads 0 "out.m3u8"
root@hosted-by:~/test#
```

and checking, ffmpeg still running

```
ps -a         
PID    TTY          TIME CMD
1359   pts/0    00:00:23 ffmpeg
1364   pts/3    00:00:00 ps
```

So my question is is there anyway to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

`cpulimit` sends SIGSTOP and SIGCONT signals to tasks to keep them below the threshold - I assume this doesn't work with ffmpeg because it uses a lot of CPU all the time.

You can set the `nice`ness on it so it's a low priority task which will allow other processes to run with a higher priority.

You could also use control groups (cgroups) to limit the resources available to the process.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I had been using avconv before switching to ffmpeg simply because avconv doesn't support -hls_key_info_file, and avconv work perfectly fine with cpulimit. I made my decision to switch back to avconv after a few hours struggling with the problem. Thank you for spending time answer my question, I'll try those if I jump back to ffmpeg in the future.